# Complex numbers $a$ and $b$ so image of $\{1 < \text{Re} z < 2\}$ under the map $\exp(az + b)$ is the upper half plane $\{\text{Im} z > 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Question says

*Find a pair of complex numbers $a$ and $b$ such that the image of the strip $\{1 < \text{Re}(z) < 2\}$ under the map $\exp(az + b)$ is the upper half plane $\{\text{Im}(z) > 0\}$*

I knew that under $e^z$, horizontal strip $\{2\pi < \text{Im}(z) < 3\pi \}$ gets mapped to {\text{Im}(z) > 0}. So I tried to find $a,b$ such that $\{1 < \text{Re}(z)< 2\}$ gets mapped to $\{2\pi < \text{Im}(z) < 3\pi \}$ under $az + b$. So first I rotated and scaled my vertical strip by multiplying by $\pi i$, i.e., $a=\pi i$. So we got horizontal strip $\{ \pi < \text{Im}(z) < 2\pi \}$. We just now needed to shift it up, so I added $\pi i$, i.e., $b=\pi i$. Is my argument correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: It looks fine...but instead of the strip $\;\{2\pi < Im(z) < 3\pi \}\;$, you could use the probably simpler strip  $\;\{0 < Im(z) < \pi \}\;$ ...

Comment: Ya.. u r right..